# Handling unchecked checkboxes when the element name uses array notation

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I have a form that is displayed in a table. This table has some elements and javascript which allows the template row to be duplicated to allow the user to add/remove rows as they want.

Here is a simplified version of the template

```
<tr data-being_removed="false" data-type="pickup" id="stop_table_row_template" style="display: none;">
    <td>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin: 0px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="stops[stop_number][]">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input class="form-check-input mt-0" name="stops[require_appointment][]" type="checkbox" value="1">
                &nbsp;Req. Appt.
            </div>
        </div>
        <select placeholder="Location" class="form-select ship_to_selector form-control-sm mt-1" name="stops[location_id][]">
            <option value="">Location</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However, checkboxes are not sent to the server if they are not checked. Usually to get around this I would create a hidden input with an identical name. However, in this case, that would cause the actual checkbox to be associated to the wrong row because the hidden input will ALWAYS be sent but the checkboxes will also SOMETIMES be sent, throwing off the implied indexes.

In the current code, it does not work for the opposite reason. For example, if the user has 3 rows, but the checkbox is only checked on the 2nd row, the form thinks the checkbox belongs to the first row because there is no matching name attribute sent to the server from the first row.

I would like to avoid having to specify indexes in the name attributes themselves. Is there any way I can send a "0" value for the name of the checkbox if the one with "1" value is not checked?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the server? With javascript you could build the form data yourself.

Comment: Why not disable the checkboxes before submission? Then they wouldn't get sent and all you'd get on the server side is the hidden fields.

Comment: @imvain2 Just a normal form submission. This form is much bigger than just this table, so I'd like to avoid that if possible but may be the only solution

Comment: @HereticMonkey If I disable the checkboxes, how could I know when one of them WAS checked?

Comment: Maybe I could just remove the name attribute from the checkbox and have a hidden field that the checkbox updates directly

Comment: I assumed you had script that kept the hidden field updated with the state of the checkbox.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't  but that is what your comment lead me to and it seems to be working

Comment: Glad it worked. I do find @imvain2's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76638020/215552) to be a bit more elegant though, TBH.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I agree at a glance, but it also seems like that answer would ALWAYS send a value of `1` unless I do extra checks to also change the value of the input element depending on if it's checked or not. Also my form is submitted without javascript, so that would require me to change how the form is submitted to.

Answer (score 2):

One solution that I have below is to loop through the checkboxes and just convert the unchecked ones to type hidden. Or you could always convert them all to hidden.

This way, there aren't a mismatch of field counts.

```js
const send = document.querySelector(".send");

send.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    let fields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)");
    fields.forEach((f) => f.type = "hidden");
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr data-being_removed="false" data-type="pickup" id="stop_table_row_template">
    <td>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin: 0px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pickup Number" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="stops[stop_number][]">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input class="form-check-input mt-0" name="stops[require_appointment][]" type="checkbox" value="1">
                &nbsp;Req. Appt.
            </div>
        </div>
        <select placeholder="Location" class="form-select ship_to_selector form-control-sm mt-1" name="stops[location_id][]">
            <option value="">Location</option>
            <option value="x">Locationx</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="send">SEND</button>
```

Comment: It seems like in it's current state this would result in always submitting a value of `1` for the checkbox, regardless if it's checked or not. It would also require me to change the way I submit my form (or at least add a .submit() call to the click event listener)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was adding a hidden input field which has the name attribute associated with my checkbox, and removed the name attribute from the checkbox itself.

```
<div class="input-group-text">
    <input class="form-check-input mt-0 req_appt" name="stops[require_appointment][]" type="hidden" value="0" disabled>
    <input class="form-check-input mt-0 req_appt_checkbox" type="checkbox">
    &nbsp;Req. Appt.
</div>
```

Then, when the checkbox is changed, it updates the hidden input.

```
$(document).on('change', '.req_appt_checkbox', function() {
    let e = $(this);
    e.closest('div').find('.req_appt').val(e.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0);
});
```